# How to prevent the queue aligned by device from being restricted in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I use Apache IoTDB Version 1.1.0 to try to query more than 500 time series using "align by device" command, and an error appears: "org.apache.iotdb.rpc.StatementExecutionException: 305: cannot fetch schema, status is: 301, msg is: The queue is full". Seems like If there are too many time series being queried, this error will appear, but when I used Version 0.13 this problem did not occur. Is there a way to prevent the queue from being restricted?

Does anyone can deal this problem？ Help please

Answer (score 0):

We have fixed this problem in Apache IoTDB Version 1.1.0, so you can try to update to this newest version to see if this error still remains.